# awk - pattern match then first row then last column

Tags: awk

my output is below, using awk I need to use the pattern match "Memory" and then Print the first row, then print the last column/1024,

The result should be 32 or 32768, this can be achieved by different sequence of commands like ,

```
grep "Memory" /var/tmp/file.out | tail -1 |  awk '{print $NF/1024}'
```

the above command will called so many times, so am looking for a single command inside awk.

```
 Data:
     Status = Running
     Memory (MB) = 32768
     Max. Memory (MB) = 32768
     Processors = 16
     Max. Processors = 16
     Priority = 50
     Processor Cap = 100
     High Availability = No
```

Comment: can you add complete expected output within code tags? there are two lines matching `Memory` in given sample... and to remove grep, use `awk '/search regex/{code}'`

Comment: Judi-dev-01# grep Memory /var/tmp/vm.out | tail -1 |  awk '{print 
        $NF/1024}'
        32
      Judi-dev-01#

Comment: looking all this three happen in single command inside awk

Comment: btw, using `tail -1` in your chain does not return the first row but the last row of `Memory` lines.

Answer (score 1):

The awk implementation of the shell pipeline in the question would be:

```
awk '/Memory/{v=$NF;f=1}END{if(f)print v/1024}' file
```

For the example input it will print

```
32
```

Comment: Your solution is equivalent to `tail -1` == prints the last row of `Memory` matched lines. If the target was to print the first row == the first `Memory` line, then solution could be as simple as `awk '/Memory/{print $NF/1024;exit}'`. If OP wants last or first line is a puzzle....

Comment: Right. The OP is using tail -1 in the question.

Comment: PS: I realized that the text in the question doesn't fit the actual command but decided to just translate the command 1:1 to awk.

Answer (score 0):

I think with the requirement of "Print the first row" that this is what you want?

```
$ awk 'flush() { if (p) { print c; print r; p = 0 } }
       BEGIN { p = 0 }
       /^[^:]+:/   { flush(); c = $0 }
       /Memory.*=/ { r = $NF/1024; p = 1 }
       END   { flush() }
       ' /var/tmp/file.out
 Data:
32
```